# How to use a string from a main java file in a separate method?

Tags: java, string

I'm pretty new to java and have been doing fine when it come to using integers, floats etc but struggling to input data from a string.
The following code/method works fine when I add to string to it, but a cant fathom how to fetch the String v from the main java file and use it in arrays in this method.
Thanks

```
public int compute_product (String v) {
    
    System.out.println(v);
    
    String text = v;
    
    String[] textStr = text.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i < textStr.length; i++) {
    }
    
            
    int[] num = new int[textStr.length];
    for(int i=0;i<num.length;i++) {
        num[i] = Integer.parseInt(textStr[i]);  
        
    }
      int product = Arrays.stream(num).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
        
      return product;
```

Comment: You need to look at Java firstly from an OO perspective, not as a procedural language, because if your going to use it like that, there are much better languages in which you can work much faster and more freely. I suggest you being with the [Oracle trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html) on Object Orientation

Answer (score 0):

From your main method you need to create a new instance of the class where you compute_product method recides.
Then you call the method of that instance variable giving the string as a parameter. The result you would probably store in a new variable in the main class.